# Can another user see a file even if they don't have any permissions?

Tags: permissions, directory

If I have a file that has 700 or 600 permissions, can other users see the file? Of course they won't be able to read the contents, but are they still able to see that it *exists* (i.e. see it's filename with the `ls` command)?

Also, is this affected by the permission of the directory it's in? If another user has permissions to the directory, can they still see/modify/delete the file, even though they don't have permissions to the file itself?

Comment: See it with ls ? Yes. If you rename it with a leading dot , then they wont see it with ls , but only ls -a. Delete and modify even if they have permissions to folder ? No. They're not the file owner , hence can't delete or modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see a file (not its contents, only the file itself), you need to have read permission for the file's parent directories. There are no "view" permissions. As long as you can read a directory, you will be able to see all the files in it. Whether or not you can modify the file or read its contents will depend on whether you have execute permissions on the directory (needed to delete the file). In more detail:

1. If you have no **read** access to the directory, you can see the names of its contents but not their characteristics (permissions, owner, creation date etc.). This is because you need read access to, well, read that information:

   ```
   $ ls -l
   total 4
   drw-rw-rw- 3 terdon terdon 4096 May  2 20:21 dir1
   $ ls -l dir1/
   ls: cannot access dir1/subdir1: Permission denied
   ls: cannot access dir1/file1: Permission denied
   total 0
   -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file1
   d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? subdir1
   ```
2. If you don't have **execute** permission on the directory, you can't read its contents even if you have read access to the directory because listing its contents requires you to be able to open ("execute") the directory:

   ```
   $ ls -l 
   total 4
   d-wx-wx-wx 3 terdon terdon 4096 May  2 20:21 dir1
   $ ls -l dir1/
   ls: cannot open directory dir1/: Permission denied
   ```
3. If you don't have **write** access to the directory, you can see its files but can't delete/create them, *even if you have read/write access to the file*. This is because creating or removing a file from a directory involves modifying the directory itself (since you're modifying its contents) and you need write access for that:

   ```
   $ ls -l
   total 4
   dr-xr-xr-x 3 terdon terdon 4096 May  2 20:21 dir1
   $ ls -l dir1/
   total 4
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon    0 May  2 20:21 file1
   drwxr-xr-x 3 terdon terdon 4096 May  2 20:19 subdir1
   $ rm dir1/file1 
   rm: cannot remove ‘dir1/file1’: Permission denied
   $ touch dir1/file2
   touch: cannot touch ‘dir1/file2’: Permission denied
   ```

The first step is to have access to the directory the file resides in. As you saw above, having all rights to the file is not enough if you don't have the needed rights to the parent directory. Assuming you have full access to the directory, yes, the file can be seen irrespective of the file's permissions:

```
$ ls -l dir1/
total 0
---------- 1 bob bob 0 May  4 15:45 file1
$ cat dir1/file1 
cat: dir1/file1: Permission denied
$ echo "foo" > dir1/file1 
bash: dir1/file1: Permission denied
```

I have no rights whatsoever to the file above but can still see it. I can neither edit it, nor read it, but I can see that it exists. I can, however, delete it:

```
$ rm dir1/file1 
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘dir1/file1’? y
```

This is because I have write access to the parent directory. I can therefore modify its contents, including any files there. If I were to remove the write access from the directory, then I wouldn't be able to delete the file, as explained above.

So, to hide a file from a user, you need to make sure that user has no read access to the file's parent directory. The permissions of the file itself are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Bellow you can see me make a test folder and change the ownership of that folder to another user. I cannot create a file if the directory isn't owned by me. Similarly, as `testuser`, I couldn't remove a test file owned by my account. But as you see, if a user can run `sudo`, that user can change ownership of the folder, change file permissions, and thus - view and modify the file

```
$ mkdir tester
$ chown testuser:testuser tester/
chown: changing ownership of ‘tester/’: Operation not permitted

$ sudo chown testuser:testuser tester/                                 
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 

$ ls -l tester
total 0

$ touch tester/testfile                                                
touch: cannot touch ‘tester/testfile’: Permission denied

$ sudo chown xieerqi:xieerqi tester/                                   
$ touch tester/testfile                                                
$ chmod 700 tester/testfile
mksh: chmod: can't execute: Permission denied

$ sudo chmod 700 tester/testfile                                       
$ sudo su testuser

testuser@foo $ ls -l tester/testfile 
-rwx------ 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 May  2 08:46 tester/testfile
testuser@foo $ rm tester/testfile
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘tester/testfile’? 
testuser@foo $ ls -l tester/testfile 
-rwx------ 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 May  2 08:46 tester/testfile
```